# Image tag generation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If working in Rails, what's the best way to define a helper function that generates many image tags?  This function would then be called from a .erb file, producing a view.

In other words, something like

```
def build_view; image_tag("seg-433.png", :alt => "Shit don't work", :class => "round"); end
```

but that returns many tags.

Feel free to suggest a more idiomatic approach, I just started riding the Rails train, like, yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an image model you could create a helper like this:

/app/helpers/my_controller_helper.rb

```
module MyControllerHelper
  def bunch_of_image_tags
    images = []
    Image.all.each do |image|
      images << image_tag(image.path, :alt => image.alt, :class => image.class)
    end
    images.join("<br/>")
  end
end
```

You could also get a list of files from the file system, but I'm not sure what you would use for the alt tag in that case. Also look at paper_clip - https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Comment: images < image_tag(image.path, :alt => image.alt, :class => image.class)

Answer (score 0):

You could render a collection of partials which contains everything you need for your image tag.

```
render :partial => "image", :collection => @images
```

the partial "image" being the one containing the image tag.
[More at api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html).